# Remove objects, and child objects from a list in C# where they match an object property in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I need a C# LINQ query where I remove objects in a list based on whether they match a property in another list.  In addition, those objects can contain children of the same type and I need to remove them as well if there is not a match.

In my example, I also want to remove the children of children.  The match doesn't need to be hierarchical - just a basic match.  Here are my classes and my failed attempt.  Any help would be awesome!

```
public class GsdMegaMenu
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public int PortalId { get; set; }   
        public int TabId { get; set; }  
    }


public class MenuItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public int PortalId { get; set; }   
        public int TabId { get; set; }
        public List<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }

    }


List<GsdMegaMenu> megaMenuItems = GsdMegaMenu.GetAllGsdMegaMenus();
RootNode.Children.RemoveAll(x => !megaMenuItems.Any(y => y.TabId == x.TabId));
```

Comment: Thanks  - you are correct, I updated the codebase.  Any idea on the error I get when implementing @Cyral code snippet?

Comment: Your code looks like you are only removing immediate children. Not children of children. Is that right?

Comment: @zespri - yes, I am trying to remove the children, and the children of children, that do not match the TabId property of the comparable List<T>.  The code below looks like it should work but I get an error about converting the list to a system predicate.  I don't know what that means...

Comment: So, what's wrong with the code in your question (not in that answer)? Are you gettting a error?

Comment: My code works, it just doesn't take in to account the children of the children - just the direct children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to also process children of children you would have to explicitly loop though them. [RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not a linq method it's a method on the `List` class. You will need to call it on every children list.

```
RootNode.Children.RemoveAll(x => megaMenuItems.All(y => y.TabId != x.TabId));
foreach (MenuItem node in RootNode.Children)
{
    if (node.Children != null)
    {
        node.Children.RemoveAll(x => megaMenuItems.All(y => y.TabId != x.TabId));
    }
 }
```

**Update**

If you are after purely LINQ solution it has to be read-only, that is it can't manipulate existing lists, it can create new ones. I would not recommend it in your case though. In your case the loop above seems more fitting.

```
RootNode = RootNode.Children.Where(x => megaMenuItems.Select(y => y.TabId).Contains(x.TabId))
    .Select(z => new MenuItem
    {
        Id = z.Id, PortalId = z.PortalId, TabId = z.TabId, 
        Children = z.Children == null ? null 
            : z.Children.Where(x => megaMenuItems.Select(y => y.TabId).Contains(x.TabId)).ToList()       
    })
    .ToList();
```

For efficiency (not that it would matter in your case), you could also rewrite it as this:

```
Func<MenuItem, bool> predicate = x => megaMenuItems.Select(y => y.TabId).Contains(x.TabId);
RootNode = RootNode.Children.Where(predicate)
    .Select(z => new MenuItem
    {
        Id = z.Id, PortalId = z.PortalId, TabId = z.TabId, 
        Children = z.Children == null ? null
            : z.Children.Where(predicate).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is fantastic - perfect!  One more thing... What if I wanted to take it one more level down to remove the nodes if the children of the children had a match.  Again - thank you!

Comment: Nest another loop in then =)